# Number the rows and reset the counter back to 1 on certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

How can I reset a counter in SQL Server on a keyword? In the following data, everytime the string 'A' is found, the counter needs to be reset to 1:

```
Item    Date
A       01.01.2019
B       02.01.2019
C       03.01.2019
D       04.01.2019
A       05.01.2019
B       06.01.2019
A       07.01.2019
B       08.01.2019
C       09.01.2019
D       10.01.2019
E       11.01.2019
A       12.01.2019
A       13.01.2019
A       14.01.2019
B       15.01.2019
```

And I need to reset the counter everytime `A` is found:

```
Count    Item    Date
1        A       01.01.2019
2        B       02.01.2019
3        C       03.01.2019
4        D       04.01.2019
1        A       05.01.2019
2        B       06.01.2019
1        A       07.01.2019
2        B       08.01.2019
3        C       09.01.2019
4        D       10.01.2019
5        E       11.01.2019
1        A       12.01.2019
1        A       13.01.2019
1        A       14.01.2019
2        B       15.01.2019
```

Comment: From your question sample, it appears that is always A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, etc... If there is no holes in your series, can you just map A=>1, B=>2, C=> 3 etc...?

Comment: Can there be more than one item on the same date? Could item `'A'` repeat on a single date?

Comment: I was just simplifying my problem. Item is the name of a batchjob and Date is a timestamp. I have a series of log entries for subjobs and I need to find those who are from the same batch run. It is a bit tricky, because the last job is not allways identical, due to errors. The start (A) is always defined, but the end point can be (D), (B) or just (A) itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN Item = 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS GroupNum
    FROM t
)
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupNum ORDER BY Date) AS [Count]
FROM cte
ORDER BY Date
```

The cte assigns a running count to each row that increments whenever `A` is encountered. Rows are the assigned a `ROW_NUMBER()` based on this counter.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2cf9979779493d9e49f7476b865235ef)